# Schengen visa with R/AT under remarks

Tags: schengen-visas, france, austria, madagascar

I applied for a C type Schengen Visa at the French Embassy in Antananarivo, Madagascar.

My plan is to go to Austria (as primary destination) first and then on to France.

My visa contains a remark **R/AT**, what does that mean?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But does that prevent me from staying for few days in France? Thanks

Comment: No, it does not.  You can go to France.

Answer (score 5):

> Mandatory     entries     to     be     added     in     the     ‘COMMENTS’     section
>
> —   in  the  case  of  a  visa  issued  on  behalf  of  another  Member  State  pursuant  to  Article  8,  the  following  mention  is  added:  ‘R/[Code  of  represented  Member  State]’

It was issued **on behalf of** Austria.

Source: [REGULATION  (EC)  No  810/2009  OF  THE  EUROPEAN  PARLIAMENT  AND  OF  THE  COUNCIL
of  13  July  2009
establishing  a  Community  Code  on  Visas
(Visa  Code)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2009:243:0001:0058:EN:PDF), Annex VII, 9 (a).

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up of @user24582 correct answer:

The C-Visa issued for Austria was issued by France:

- [France](https://mg.ambafrance.org/Informations-sur-les-visas-2160)

  - **Austria**, Belgium, Czech Republic, Estonia, Germany, Greece, Iceland, Italy, Luxembourg, Portugal, Slovenia and Spain
- [Switzerland](https://www.eda.admin.ch/countries/madagascar/en/home/visa/entry-ch/up-90-days/where-to-apply-schengen.html)

  - Hungry, Netherlands, Norway, Poland and Sweden
- **Unknown**

  - Denmark, Finland, Latvia, Lithuania, Malta, Slovakia

It is not all that easy to find the needed information about who represents who.

**Other sources**:

- [List of diplomatic missions in Madagascar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_in_Madagascar)
- [Annex 22 National entries in the "comments" section of the visa sticker](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/visa_sticker_comments_section_en.pdf)

  - Pdf with a list of **country** specific codes/remarks

Comment: downvoter, care to comment why giving extra information is considered to be **negative**?